# Get data out of enum

Tags: rust

I have a function that received an enum with some data that I don't know inside. How can I retrieve its single values? For ex:

```
pub enum Type1{
    Original {
      A: u32,
      B: u32,
    },
  
    Plus {
      A: u32,
      C: u32,
    },
  }

let bp = Type1::Original { A: 3, B: 4 };
// I have received bp but I want to work with bp.A
// How can I print it for example?

println!("{}", bp.A);
// Gives me the error: error[E0609]: no field `A` on type `Type1`
```

Comment: Do you mean to get `A` only for one variant or for whatever active? Because my and @aedm's solutions differ in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`if let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/if_let.html):

```rust
if let Type1::Original { A, B } = bp {
    println!("{}", A);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=99ee04fc5831f4ad0cf7b7ff38f1a554)

Answer (score 4):

Use pattern matching:

```rust
let a = match bp {
    Type1::Original { A, .. } => A,
    Type1::Plus { A, .. } => A,
};
println!("{}", a);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=47cbe7393c9ddfa5c91043fc9b0570b3).